# How to get the minCardinality of properties?

Tags: ontology, owl, jena, cardinality

I am using Jena. How can I get the minCardinality of a property?

Answer (score 1):

Try asking on SemanticOverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess... it's [a class assignment](http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/1920/mincardinality-of-properties)? Maybe ask Fateme. :)